# Is it association or aggregation?

Tags: java, oop

I'm trying to understand object oriented approach by the following simple example:

I have the class:

```
public class TotalRestiction{

    private Restriction r;

    public add(RestictionItem i){
        //updating the Restriction field
        //depends on the RestrictionItem
    }

    private static class Restriction{
        //...
    }

    public Collection<Object> getObjects(){
        //...
    }
}

public interface RestrictionItem{

    //...
}
```

It's not clear to me what is the exact relationship between those classes. Is it aggregation or association? I tend to say that it's aggregation, because the `TotalRestriction` aggregates the `RestrictionItem`s, encapsulated within the `Restriction` static nested class. But I'm not pretty sure about that.

Comment: I would say **association** with internally in the class **aggregation**. A kind of (black) box recursion. In order to have a database scheme, maybe only aggregation.

Comment: @JoopEggen Sounds like it's not quite a good thing... Does it smell like a bad design?

Comment: No, entirely not. In fact hiding things like a caching class, and many other abstractions with internal functionality, that is just a way - embedding - of having nice functionality that can be reused. It is more like a nice jewel; hence I mentioned box-in-box.

Comment: what's the relationship between Restriction and RestrictionItem? If RestrictionItem is a public interface, how can it refer to private class Restriction? (you are saying it encapsulates it)

Comment: @eis It doesn't. I use it only for creating the Restiriction. RestrictionItems are building vlocks for it.

Comment: you are also saying that TotalRestriction aggregates the RestrictionItem instances, but I see no such thing, as the only private variable is Restriction, not a RestrictionItem.

Comment: @eis Yes, but actually the Restriction does...

Answer (score 1):

[Association](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_%28object-oriented_programming%29) would be when it would use another class, which does not have to be encapsulated. [Composition](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/oop-concepts/composition-and-aggregation.html) would be when your class has a has-a relationship with those classes, e.g. TotalRestriction has-a RestrictionItems. With [Aggregation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/61376/aggregation-vs-composition) the class also has a has-a relationship, but the other classes also exist independently of the parent class, which is not the case with Composition..

In your case, I'd say Restriction class has a aggregation relationship towards RestrictionItem, and TotalRestriction has a composition relationship towards Restriction.

Answer (score 0):

If you are instantiating class TotalRestriction as:

```
TotalRestriction tr=new TotalRestriction(new Restriction());
```

and 
   in TotalRestriction class constructor is as :

```
   class TotalRestriction{
      Restriction r;
      public TotalRestriction(Restriction r){
         this.r=r;
      }
   }
```

then it is Aggregation

if you are using like this:

```
class TotalRestriction{
      Restriction r;
      public TotalRestriction(){
         r=new Restriction();
      }
   }
```

then it is Association  because class TotalRestriction uses service of class Restriction .

Comment: You are not taking into account RestrictionItem in any way. OP was asking what is the relationship "between classes", I'd assume it would mean all the listed classes... also, the first example you give is not even possible as Restriction is a private class.